# Searching Arrays in Java: equals( ) Versus == 

Tags: arrays, search, loops, equals

I have an array with 5 elements. If a user inputs a name or a title, it should output that person's or job title's corresponding job title and person. Here's what I got, I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong. Since it's an applet, I don't need a main method right? Did I get stuff mixed up? What could I be doing wrong? Even if I input data that is stored in the array, it always gives me "input did not match any records" I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Assignment extends JApplet implements ActionListener

{



String[] empName = {"John Jacobs" , "Will Watts","Kevin Krust", "Allan Ayers", "Sam Smith"};

String[] empTitle = {"Software Engineer" , "Database Administrator", "Network Administrator" , "Head Programmer" ,"Department Manager"};

final int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

boolean validName = false;

boolean validTitle = false;

String nameOfEmployee;

String titleOfEmployee;





JLabel enterInfo = new JLabel("Enter an Employee Name or Job Title");

JTextField userInput = new JTextField(20);

JButton empButton = new JButton ("Press if you entered a name");

JButton titleButton = new JButton ("Press if you entered a title");

JLabel inputDisplay = new JLabel("");

Container con = getContentPane();

public void init()

{

    con.add(enterInfo);

    con.add(userInput);        

    con.add(empButton);

    con.add(titleButton);

    con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    userInput.addActionListener(this);

    empButton.addActionListener(this);

    titleButton.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)

{

    Object source = event.getSource();

    if (source == empButton)

    {

        String nameEmp = userInput.getText();

        con.remove(enterInfo);

        con.remove(userInput);

        con.remove(empButton);

        con.remove(titleButton);

        for (int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; ++x)

            {

              if (nameEmp == empName[x])

                {

                    validName = true;

                    titleOfEmployee = empTitle[x];

                }

            }

            if(validName)

            inputDisplay.setText(nameEmp + "is a" + titleOfEmployee);



            else



            inputDisplay.setText("The title you input did not match any records.");



        con.add(inputDisplay);

        con.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);        



    }



    else

    {

        String nameJob = userInput.getText();

        con.remove(enterInfo);

        con.remove(userInput);

        con.remove(empButton);

        con.remove(titleButton);

        for (int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; ++x)

            {

              if (nameJob == empTitle[x])

                {

                    validTitle = true;

                    nameOfEmployee = empName[x];

                }

            }

            if(validName)

            inputDisplay.setText(nameOfEmployee + "is a" + nameJob);

            else

            inputDisplay.setText("The name you input did not match any records.");

        con.add(inputDisplay);

        con.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    }

    con.invalidate();

    con.validate();

}

}
```

Comment: please try `if( nameJob.equals(empTitle[x]) )` instead of `if(nameJob == empTitle[x])  if (nameJob == empTitle[x])` Also check nameJob for Nullity before comparing with `equals()`

Comment: how could i have not remembered that. thank you for the clarification! now this is something i will never forget haha. thanks guys! and thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
nameEmp == empName[x]
```

compares object references. What you want is comparison of contents, so you should check

```
nameEmp.equals(empName[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the value input by the user to the values in your arrays, you need to use the `equals` function and not `==`.
[Read why here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221).